# I am confused with the decomposition of table in database design. Is the decomposition correct?

Tags: database, database-design, database-normalization

The table has following information

```
SchoolName  |  Medium   |  Board
------------+-----------+-------
DPS         |  English  |  CBSE
DPS         |  English  |  ICSE
St.Xavier   |  English  |  CBSE
St.Xavier   |  English  |  GSEB
Gurukul     |  English  |  GSEB
Gurukul     |  Hindi    |  GSEB
```

The above table is decomposed as:.

```
SchoolID  | SchoolName
----------+-----------
1         | DPS
2         | St.Xavier
3         | Gurukul 

MediumID  | Medium
----------+-----------
1         | English
2         | Hindi

BoardID  | Board
---------+-----------
1        | CBSE
2        | ICSE
3        | GSEB
```

And relationship as shown in below image.

Is the decomposition correct to store and retrieve the information?

**Table and relationships as relational schema**
[image: Table and relationships as relational schema]

Comment: Make first table as `SchoolID | SchoolName | MediumID | BoardID`

Comment: Yes. I got it. Will this give me lossless join only? What I am asking is that there won't be any extra or less information by this decomposition?

Comment: 1) Normalization through BCNF is based on functional dependencies. What are the functional dependencies? 2) Normalization doesn't introduce new attributes.

Comment: @JitendraSoftgrid Clearly not, because it introduces new column names. See the comment by MikeSherrill'CatRecall'.

Comment: Hi. Tell us your textbook & quote relevant definitions & processes like "decomposition" or "component" & show us your work following them. Google 'stackexchange homework'. PS Are you decomposing that *value* or *variable* (base table) that could hold it?

Comment: Hi. Please [use text, not images/links, for text (including code, tables & ERDs)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use an image only for convenience to supplement text and/or for what cannot be given in text. And never give a diagram without a legend/key.